# Clear existing messages in activemq queue, just after starting application using activemq-cpp

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I have an application which is acting as a consumer for a queue in activemq. This application is written on c++ and using activemq-cpp to get the services of activemq.

I want to achieve is when my application goes down and again comes up, it should first delete all the messages which gets populated in queue during the time my application is down that is it should first delete all the old messages in queue and then starts receiving new messages.

Is there any way to achieve this using activemq-cpp?

Answer (score 1):

If you cast your Connection instance to an ActiveMQConnection there is a destroyDestination method that will remove the destination from the broker and all messages if there are no active subscriptions when called, otherwise it will throw an exception so be prepared for that.  A small code snippet follows.

```
    ActiveMQConnection* connection =
        dynamic_cast<ActiveMQConnection*>( cmsConnection );

    try {
        connection->destroyDestination(destination);
    } catch(Exception& ex) {
    }
```